# Using Python to turn a list of tuples into a histogram/barchart

Tags: python, data-visualization

I'm working with a dataset that is encoded like so:

```
[
    [
        (u'90000', 100318), 
        (u'21000', 58094), 
        (u'50000', 14695), 
        (u'250000', 8190), 
        (u'100000', 5718), 
        (u'40000', 4276)
    ]
]
```

I'd like to transmogrify it into a histogram/barchart.

I've been looking at XXX, thus far I've tried like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.bar(x, counts)
plt.xticks(counts[0], counts[1])

plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.show()
```

However, it generated the error:

```
NameError: name 'formatter' is not defined
```

The code used to generate that data structure looks like this:

```
with open('toy_two.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    dict_hash_gas = list()
    for line in inpt:
        resource = json.loads(line)
        dict_hash_gas.append({resource['first']:resource['second']})

# Count up the values
counts = collections.Counter(v for d in dict_hash_gas for v in d.values())

counts = counts.most_common()

# Apply a threshold
threshold = 4275
counts = [list(group) for val, group in itertools.groupby(counts, lambda x: x[1] > threshold) if val]

print(counts)
```

And the data like this:

```
{"first":"A","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"B","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"C","second":"2","third":"2"} 
{"first":"D","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"E","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"F","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"G","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"H","second":"4","third":"2"} 
{"first":"I","second":"4","third":"2"} 
{"first":"J","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"K","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"L","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"M","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"N","second":"0","third":"2"}
```

---

**The question:**

To be clear, the question is: how to render the data at the beginning of this post, i.e.

```
[
    [
        (u'90000', 100318), 
        (u'21000', 58094), 
        (u'50000', 14695), 
        (u'250000', 8190), 
        (u'100000', 5718), 
        (u'40000', 4276)
    ]
]
```

as a histogram?

The x-axis would be `u'90000'`, `u'21000'`, ..., `u'40000'`.

The y-axis would be `100318`, `58094`, ..., `4276`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: question is- how to render that data as a histogram

Comment: What is `plt`? and `fig` and `ax`?

Comment: added it as an edit to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [
    [
        (u'90000', 100318), 
        (u'21000', 58094), 
        (u'50000', 14695), 
        (u'250000', 8190), 
        (u'100000', 5718), 
        (u'40000', 4276)
    ]
]
```

Transpose the data to get the x and y values

```
#data = data[0]
#x, y = zip(*data)
x, y = zip(*data[0])
```

Compress the y values so they will fit on the screen

```
import math
y = [int(math.log(n, 1.5)) for n in y]
```

Iterate over the data and create the histogram

```
for label, value in zip(x, y):
    print('{:>10}: {}'.format(label, 'x'*value))


>>>
     90000: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     21000: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     50000: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    250000: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    100000: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     40000: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>>>
```

Comment: `x, y = zip(*data[0])` is probably better so you don't mutate the original data.

Comment: so- that is totally awesome- and super creative- but I was kind of more thinking like, to render it in mat plot lib or something like that, you know?

Comment: @s.matthew.english - I didn't know: there was nothing in the question regarding that.

Comment: true- that's why I marked it as the correct answer. but- I was thinking- to render it suitable to matplotlib I could maybe just assign the x and y values to functions of that library, isn't it?

Comment: @s.matthew.english - hmmm ... maybe look through [the gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) for [something suitable](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html)